# backdoor php trojan still dangerous on my local machine?

Tags: virus, backdoor

I recently removed and fixed a lot of backdoor trojans in some files in one of my servers, and I copied those files to my local computer. But the issue is that now that I run the virus scanner on my computer, it says they are dangerous and need to be deleted.

So far as I know, you can't execute php files if they are not in a server, so why does it say this? Because of the regx and base64 functions calls? Or is it actually possible to get hacked from these files in a random place in another computer which is not a server?

Comment: I think you are missing some crucial info in your question. You removed the files with backdoors and copied them to your local computer and your AV reports them as malicious? And you want to know if they are still malicious even though you are not serving them on a web server?

Comment: yes that is right, I remove it from my server but I still have a copy of it in a local HD, so I guess is just getting pick up because of the regx and the way is build, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, anti-virus will report a file as malicious even if that file cannot be executed on the machine it is on. For instance, a Windows-only virus found on a Mac can still be identified by anti-virus as malicious.

This is a good thing because you might pass on those files to others. Malicious is malicious, even if there isn't an imminent threat to the local machine.

Comment: great thanks for making that clear for me, really helpful